# How to get text from span class in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
<th>     
    <span class="firstLanguage">Zeit</span>
</th>
<th>
    <span class="firstLanguage">Nach</span>
</th>
<th>
    <span class="firstLanguage"> </span>
</th>
<th>
    <span class="firstLanguage">Über</span>
</th>
<th>
    <span class="firstLanguage">Gleis</span>
</th>
```

How can I extract the text from span tags in selenium. 
Is it via classname, but all four class = "firstLanguage"

Answer (score 4):

You can try below snippet.

```
 int count = selenium.getXpathCount("//span[@class='firstLanguage']").intValue();
 for(int i =1 ; i <= count ; i ++){
         System.out.println(selenium.getText("//span["+i+"]"));
 }
```

This will return you all the span elements defined by the class `firstLanguage` and you can iterate the list to take text out of them.

Answer (score 3):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/span")).getText();
```

will display "**Zeit**"

    `driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/span[2]")).getText();`

will display "**Nach**"

likewise

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/span[5]")).getText();`

will display "**Gleis**"

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use the [nth-child](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthchild) pseudoclass to do that, for example

```
.firstLanguage:nth-child(2)
```

Comment: @Amith It was a long day. :)

Answer (score 0):

Using this code:

```
 List<WebElement> elements =driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*/div/table/tbody/tr/th/span"));
            for(WebElement ele:elements)
            {
            System.out.println(ele.getText());
            }
```

will display all the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Better implementation would be by making use of findElements, please check below code

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.className("firstLanguage"));
for(WebElement element : elements){
   System.out.println(element.getText());
}
```

You can also make use of other locators as below

```
xpath = //th//span[@class='firstLanguage']

css = th span[class='firstLanguage']
```